# What I have done wrong that I call a dll from VB6

Tags: visual-c++, dll, vb6

I have a legacy project was written many years ago which written with VB 6. I can't find enough information of VB 6 on Google due to VB 6 is too old.

I'm  trying to call a DLL from VB 6 which is written in VC++. The problem is when VB calling the dll, VB has been crashed. I thought it was the errors of DLL, then I debug the DLL. However, I have found the dll works fine. It finally return 0, but the VB pass the double array is not successful, however the DLL works OK.and then when dll exectued finished and return to VB, VB then be crashed. I can't figure out what happend. Any idea?

Here is my VB code

```
 Declare Function parseexcel Lib "parseexcelct.dll" (ByVal thepath As String, ByRef total() As Double, ByRef xy() As Double, ByRef ylxx() As Double, ByRef zy() As Double, ByRef zcy() As Double, ByRef gj1 As Double, ByRef gj2 As Double, ByRef xs1 As Double, ByRef xs2 As Double, ByVal gjt1 As Double, ByVal gjt2 As Double, ByVal xst1 As Double, ByVal xst2 As Double) As Long


Dim mypathstr As String

Dim total(0 To 20) As Double

Dim xy(0 To 20) As Double
Dim ylxx(0 To 20) As Double
Dim zy(0 To 20) As Double
Dim zcy(0 To 20) As Double

Dim gj1 As Double, gj2 As Double, xs1 As Double, xs2 As Double, gjt1 As  Double
Dim gjt2 As Double, xst1 As Double, xst2 As Double
Dim result As Integer

 mypathstr = CommonDialog.FileName
 Dim i As Integer

  'try to initial the array
   For i = 0 To 20
   total(i) = 1.1
   xy(i) = 1.1
   ylxx(i) = 1.1
   zy(i) = 1.1
   zcy(i) = 1.1
   Next i

   result = 0
   gj1 = 1.1
   gj2 = 1.1
   xs1 = 1.1
   xs2 = 1.1
   gjt1 = 1.1
   gjt2 = 1.1
   xst1 = 1.1
   xst2 = 1.1

   result = parseexcel(mypathstr, total(), xy(), ylxx(), zy(), zcy(), gj1, gj2, xs1, xs2, gjt1, gjt2, xst1, xst2)'program have crashed here
```

DLL function is

```
  int __stdcall parseexcel(const char * thepath,double * total,double * xy,double * ylxx,double * zy,double * zcy,double & gj1,double & gj2,double & xs1,double & xs2,double gjt1,double gjt2,double xst1,double xst2  )
```

What I have done wrong?

Answer (score 1):

C++ uses fairly "dumb" arrays, and in any case does not use SAFEARRAY by default.  So you can't just pass a pointer to a SAFEARRAY to it, and instead it wants a pointer to the BLOB of data.

In VB6 this is often accomplished simply by passing a pointer to the beginning of the array's data by passing the first array element ByRef:

```
Declare Function parseexcel Lib "parseexcelct.dll" ( _
    ByVal thepath As String, _
    ByRef total As Double, _
    ByRef xy As Double, _
    ByRef ylxx As Double, _
    ByRef zy As Double, _
    ByRef zcy As Double, _
    ByRef gj1 As Double, _
    ByRef gj2 As Double, _
    ByRef xs1 As Double, _
    ByRef xs2 As Double, _
    ByVal gjt1 As Double, _
    ByVal gjt2 As Double, _
    ByVal xst1 As Double, _
    ByVal xst2 As Double) As Long

result = parseexcel(mypathstr, _
                    total(0), _
                    xy(0), _
                    ylxx(0), _
                    zy(0), _
                    zcy(0), _
                    gj1, _
                    gj2, _
                    xs1, _
                    xs2, _
                    gjt1, _
                    gjt2, _
                    xst1, _
                    xst2)
```

This sort of thing is pretty well covered in the VB6 documentation.

Comment: [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338032(v=VS.60).aspx) is the (well hidden) link to MSDN's VB6 reference library.  As you have seen, Microsoft have gone out of their way to make VB6 documentation difficult to find.